# pyars issue when get data from remedy database

Tags: python, database, remedy

My part code:

```
from pyars import erars
ars = erars.erARS()
self._db_login(ars)
(entries, num) = ars.GetListEntryWithFields(schema, query, fields,None) 

>>>> code will failed in GetListEntryWithFields
```

### error info:

```
File "c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-x_sfek\pyars-1.8.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyars\erars.py", line 3546, in GetListEntryWithFields
File "c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-x_sfek\pyars-1.8.2-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\pyars\erars.py", line 470, in conv2QualifierStruct
pyars.erars.ARError: An WARNING (0) occured: None
```

Sometimes i will hit the issue above, then it will succeed without any code change. I think the root cause is the db connection is not stable. But it is so boring that will happen several times. Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly hitting DB which is not recommend from BMC you can use webservice to perform your action